# More Mistakes at RPI3 + Ubuntu Server 23.04

Tags: ubuntu

Yet again, a new error.

After a **fresh install** of Raspberry Pi 3B + Ubuntu Server 23.04, immediately after successfully changing the SSH password, following this documentation, under [these specific steps](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-server):

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

wifis:
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "myntwk":
        password: "mypssw"
```

Alas, this doesn't work. This command fails, makes the RPI fails, and now it doesnt connect to SSH.

```
~$ sudo netplan apply
Cannot call openvswitch: ovsdb-server.service is not running.
```

What's happening with these guys?. They're releasing faulty instructions on purpose?

Comment: if you search for "ovsdb-server.service is not running" you'll see

Comment: Why are you asking here? This is Ubuntu instruction for a Ubuntu image - ask on a Ubuntu site.